# VBA trigger to hard code cells

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

I have setup a control worksheet.  In Column J I have a drop down list - If "Y" is select then it triggers a UDF in column I to apply a signature (sign off).  I'm looking for a trigger to hard code to the whole row after the UDF runs.  So if "Y" in selected in any cell in column J then hard code protect/lock that entire row.

Looking for tips on how to handle/go about setting up the trigger - I think I should be able to setup the locking/protecting.  Plus I presume a time delay will allow the UDF to run before locking the row?

All advice welcome,

Thank you,

Ciaran

Comment: You may want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640) since you would be working with ` Worksheet_Change()` Also see @DougGlancy's comment below my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a worksheet change event.  Any time a change in column J is detected, the code will run.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Column = 10 Then
      'insert your code here
   End If
End Sub
```

Use `Target.Address` for the exact cell reference.  You could even incorporate your UDF code in here instead of running a separate process.

Comment: Thank you Tony for the tips.  Really appreciate the help.